# MySQL MATCH-AGAINST plural words?

Tags: php, mysql, match, against

I'd like to add a search to my site.  I have a database of challenges from a video game.  Each challenge has a title and description, I'd like to be able to search at least the description, but both if possible.  Now, I've set the table up so that I can use MATCH() AGAINST(), but I'm having a problem with words that can be either singular or plural.

For example, the word "assists" appears in multiple challenges, but if the user types "assist", he won't get anything.  Is there any way that I can add that functionalty?  I've tried everything I can think of, but nothing has worked so far.

**Update:** I only just recently learned about MATCH AGAINST, so I'm not sure the "right" way to use it in my case.  Like I said, I've got a table with a column called `description`, using the example word from above, `assists`, which appears multiple times in the table, I would use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM challenges WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST('assists')
```

I just executed that and it returned 10 rows.  If I change it to `assist`, I get nothing.

Comment: what mode of MATCH AGAINST are you using? natural language?

Comment: I added more information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the SOUNDEX() function from MySQL.

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM products AS p
WHERE p.title SOUNDS LIKE 'Shaw'

// This wil match 'Saw' etc.
```

I think this also may be applicable for you and that he will take with plurals

Comment: I tried it with this query: ``SELECT * FROM challenges WHERE description SOUNDS LIKE 'assist'`` and got nothing, I changed it to ``assists`` and still got nothing.

Comment: I checked it for you and normal 'assist' and 'assists' have the came Soundex. So they should be find by the query. You can check your Soundex on this site: http://www.searchforancestors.com/soundex.html

Comment: Ok but I'm telling you that I ran the query that I outlined in my previous comment.  I got 0 results for both the word "assist" and "assists".

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point of what you're trying to do, but why not just do a LIKE match like this:

```
SELECT * FROM challenges WHERE description LIKE "%assist%";
```

That will match anything that contains "assist" as well as "assists". Of course it will also match "assistant" and "assistance", which may not be what you want...

Comment: Yeah that's not quite what I'm looking for.  Like you said, that will match any word that also contains the search term, like if I searched for "read", it would return "thread", "bread", etc.